# Is this expression a quadratic form

Tags: quadratic-forms

I have an matrix expression that basically is of the form:

\begin{equation}
tr(B X BX )
\end{equation}

Where $B$ and $X$ and nonsquare matrices.  $B$ is $p \times n$, $X$ is $n \times p$.

It seems to me this trace expression is a quadratic form because I got it as part of a longer matrix expression which represents the Hessian term of a Taylor series approximating a matrix function.  However, I can't see to get it into the form:

\begin{equation}
\text{vec}(X)^T [H] \text{vec}(X)
\end{equation}

Where $[H]$ is the square matrix representation of this quadratic form.  I want to get it into this form so I can get the eigenvectors of this matrix $[H]$.  $\text{vec}(X)$ is the vector of length $pn$ where the columns of $X$ are on top of each other.

Can someone help me confirm whether this trace expression can indeed be converted into an explicit matrix representation?

I know that I can make this into:

\begin{equation}
\text{vec}(X^T)^T (B^T \otimes B) \text{vec}(X)
\end{equation}

But this is not what I want because it gives me $\text{vec}(X^T)$ on the left!  It seems so close yet so far.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.  Notice that the elements of $\mathrm{vec}(X^T)$ are just a reordering of $\mathrm{vec}(X)$.  The two are related by a permutation matrix that is sometimes known as a stride permutation.  If $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ then the stride permutation matrix $L_m^{mn}$ satisfies the equation $L_m^{mn}\mathrm{vec}(X)=\mathrm{vec}(X^T)$.  Therefore you have $\mathrm{trace}(BXBX)=\mathrm{vec}(X)((L_m^{mn})^T B\otimes B)\mathrm{vec}(X)$.  There is also another interesting way to obtain this result that will make future calculations simpler.  For matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m_1\times n_1}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m_2\times n_2}$
define the box product
$A\boxtimes B\in\mathbb{R}^{(m_1m_2)\times(n_1n_2)}$
by 
$$ (A\boxtimes B)_{(i-1)m_2+j,(k-1)n_1+l} = a_{il}b_{jk} "=
(A\boxtimes B)_{(ij)(kl)}" $$
then $I_m\boxtimes I_n = L_{m}^{mn}$ and you can also write
$$\mathrm{trace}(BXBX)=\mathrm{vec}^\top(X)(B\boxtimes B)\mathrm{vec}(X)$$
The box-product essentially behaves like the Kronecker product and satisfies the following properties:
\begin{eqnarray}
A\boxtimes(B\boxtimes F) &=& (A\boxtimes B)\boxtimes F \\
(A\boxtimes B)( C\boxtimes D) &=& (A D)\otimes(BC)\\
( A\boxtimes B)^\top &=& B^\top\boxtimes A^\top\\
(A\boxtimes B)^{-1} &=& B^{-1}\boxtimes A^{-1}\\
\mathrm{trace}(A\boxtimes B) &=& \mathrm{trace}(AB)\\
(A\boxtimes B)\mathrm{vec}(X) &=& \mathrm{vec}(BX^\top A^\top).
\end{eqnarray}
In addition to these Kronecker and box products can easily be multiplied using the following rules:
\begin{eqnarray}
(A\boxtimes B)(C\otimes D) &=& (AD)\boxtimes(BC)\\
(A\otimes B)(D\boxtimes C) &=& (AD)\boxtimes(BC)\\
(A\boxtimes B)(C\otimes D) &=& (A\otimes B)(D\boxtimes C)\\
(A\boxtimes B)(C\boxtimes D) &=& (A\otimes B)(D\otimes C)
\end{eqnarray}
For two two-by-two matrices the box product can explicitly be written 
$$
A\boxtimes B = \begin{pmatrix} 
a_{11}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{11} & a_{11}b_{12} & a_{12}b_{12} \\
a_{11}b_{21} & a_{12}b_{21} & a_{11}b_{22} & a_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{21}b_{11} & a_{22}b_{11} & a_{21}b_{12} & a_{22}b_{12} \\
a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{21} & a_{21}b_{22} & a_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
and here's an example stride-permutation
$$
L_2^6=I_2\boxtimes I_3 = \left(
\begin{array}{llllll}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Finally, I should mention that there is actually a mistake in the answer.  My convention has been to use row-wise concatenation of matrices and the definition above, from which easily follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{trace}(BXBX) &=& \mathrm{vec}^\top((BXB)^\top)\mathrm{vec}(X)\\
&=& \mathrm{vec}^\top(B^\top X^\top B^\top)\mathrm{vec}(X)\\
&=& \mathrm{vec}^\top(X) B\boxtimes B^\top \mathrm{vec}(X)
\end{eqnarray*}

This answer makes more sense, as the matrix $B\boxtimes B^\top$ is always symmetric, whereas $B\boxtimes B$ is not.

I struggled with questions similar to the one you just made, and the box product has been a great help to me.  I hope this was of help to you.

Comment: That "stride permutation" matrix is also called a perfect shuffle matrix isn't it?  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Should the box multiply expression: $\mathrm{trace}(BXBX)=\mathrm{vec}(X)(B\boxtimes B)\mathrm{vec}(X)$  be $\mathrm{trace}(BXBX)=\mathrm{vec}(X)^T(B\boxtimes B)\mathrm{vec}(X)$ ?

Comment: Indeed it is also called a perfect shuffle.  Physicists also use this permutation matrix, but I don't know what name they have for it.  Yes, the transform is missing. Let me actually fix it.  There are some other mistakes too.  What definition do you use for the vec operator?  row-wise or column-wise concatenation?  If you don't mind, could you also up-vote my answer, since I spent some time on it.

Comment: Read the bottom of my comment again.  I think in your calculations you also made a mistake, and it should have been $B\otimes B^\top$ and not $B\otimes B$.

Comment: I'm using the definition that you take the columns and stack them on top of each other.

Comment: In that case the correct form of the quadratic form is: $\mathrm{vec}^\top(X)B\boxtimes B^\top \mathrm{vec}(X)$.  With the column-stacking definition the answer would be $\mathrm{colvec}^\top(X)B^\top\boxtimes B\  \mathrm{colvec}(X)$

Answer (score 1):

Just think of the matrix $U = XB.$ Your matrix is $U^2,$ so write down the expression for the trace of the square, then substitute, then find the coefficient of $x_{ij}.$ It's tedious, but not difficult.

Comment: You are almost there.  Notice that the elements of $vec(X^T)$ are just a reordering of $vec(X)$, so we can write

Comment: @Peder Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Igor Rivin Are you suggestion I do SVD on U=XB =VSV^T ?